# Gson generic collection of interface

Tags: java, generics, serialization, deserialization, gson

I have the following method with `Serializable` as a self-defined interface:

```
private <T extends Synchronizable> Collection<T> deserialize(String json, Class<T> type) {
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType();
  return new Gson().fromJson(json, collectionType);
}
```

This method is not working properly since Gson expects the type token to be of a specific generic type, e.g. `Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Group>>(){}.getType();` (while `Group` implements `Serializable`).

Does anybody know a solution for this problem, or am I not able to use generic methods at this place, which would be awkward.

Comment: Your question is unclear. [look here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types) for guidance

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `type` parameter that you're accepting in there as in:

```
  private <T extends Synchronizable> Collection<T> deserialize(String json, Class<T> type){
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Class<T>>>(){}.getType();
         return new Gson().fromJson(json, collectionType);
  }
```

Comment: that does not compile since `type` cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @Benny Then just use the raw `Class<T>`. See my update

Comment: Then gson will try to deserialize a Class type.